# Is this the best way to do a "not in" in ActiveRecord 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I really like being able to:

```
Product.where(:id => [40,41,42])
```

Which generates a nice `where id in (40,41,42)`

However, I could only figure out how to do the inverse as:

```
Product.where("id not in (?)", [40,41,42])
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's how you do it. There is no shorter way, at least with vanilla ARel. You may find something within [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) that could do it though.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I might see if I can monkey patch something just for grins and giggles.  :-)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
Product.all.delete_if{|x| [41,42,43].include? x.id }
```

==> Array with all products excluding the ones with the given ids.

Comment: +1 for a neat alternative but I actually think the `not in (?)` is cleaner.

Comment: This solution will crash the server. When the `products` table has 1000s of rows, all the rows are loaded to the memory before applying `delete_if`. Filtering the database rows on the client side should be avoided religiously.